# How do I change the "[remote detached]" message in GNU Screen

Tags: gnu, gnu-screen, detach

When I remote detach a screen session and connect to it myself (screen -r -d), I see the following on the detached session.

`[remote detached]`

Is it possible to change this message?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard-coded in the screen source (line: `1745` of `screen.c` in Screen v 4.0.3):

```
#ifdef REMOTE_DETACH
    case D_REMOTE:
      AddStr("[remote detached]\r\n");
      sign = SIG_BYE;
      break;
#endif
```

You can try editing that part and recompiling the source.